# Linear regression method help?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's suppose we have  a function $Y=A\cdot t^B$ and the values for $Y$ are $30,60,90,120,150$ and the values for $t$ are respectively $0.974, 1.331, 1.718, 1.971, 2.356$. Can you find $A$ and $B$ with the method of linear regression? I have to do a lab work and this is a very small part of it, which does not count but I still have to do it and I have never done linear regression, I need this now? please?

Comment: can't you find  A and B  without regression?

Comment: I need that with the regression method..that's what it says in my paper

Comment: then i think it is not linear regression model,it is called  exponential regression

Comment: in case of  any question,please ask

Comment: this is power regression...

Comment: yes yes i have mixed,ok  then you could serach it on internet

Comment: I highly doubt that the pedagogical purpose of this question is to do power/exponential regression. A straight line can be fitted using linear least squares fit. For power/exponential regression, one has to use non-linear least squares fitting...which is much more non-trivial than LLSF.

Comment: i think so,just better would be  to give  regression exact in linear form, not so complicated

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to use a calculator or software or do you have to do this by hand? In either case, if you have $y=at^b$ then just take the logarithm of both sides and get
$$\log(y)=\log(a)+b\log(t)$$
and then use linear regression using this form of the fitting function. So remember you won't put in your data points $y$ and $t$ as you have them above. You have to take their log and use $\log(y)$ and $\log(t)$. Then the slope of the fitted line will be your $b$ because that is the coefficient in front of $\log(t)$ and the y-intercept will be $\log(a)$ so exponentiate it to get $a$ and VOILA!

Comment: exactly,in fact there is no big difference  if it is power or exponential,they have similar  solution

Comment: Yep, they wouldn't be exactly the same but they are close and in this case both answers are within 95% confidence interval of each other. The power regression gives me $a=36.45$ and $b=1.679$.

Comment: In my results I get a=30  and b=2  ..the values of t and y are not very exact because of lab work ,and in my results i get different b's and a's ( sometimes b=1.7 ,b=2.1,b=2.2 )for different systems (of y and t) so i will take a=30  and b=2, i have to take exact values because i have to build a graph ..in this case the graph will look smth like  Y=30*b^2

Answer (score 0):

http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/calctopic1/regression.html   look here it contains both linear regression and exponential regression